# Broadcast message between nest.js microservices

Tags: nestjs

I'm using Redis as transport for microservices communication.

Each @MessagePattern in controller creates two Redis channels **_ack** for Pub message and **_res** for answer on this message.

Client that are sending message - pub it into **_ack** channel and wait response by listening **_res** channel. When answer is receiving via **_res** channel we get in this packet "disposed: true"

Question:
If I create 3 microservices (different servers). Two of them will be have the same @MessagePattern and third will be send message on this pattern. This is some like broadcast messages.

**Will be sender correctly processing both answer from _res channel ?**

**Is there right way for using nestjs transport for broadcasting?**